# Modal bottom menu in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

How can I create a menu like on screenshot for react-native?

[image]

Comment: You could try https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet

Comment: I found a better cross platform solution: https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet

Answer (score 4):

you can set backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'.

```
<Modal
      animationType={"slide"}
      transparent={false}
      visible={this.state.modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}

      >

     <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'}}>
      <View style ={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', width: 300, height: 300}}>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>
          </View>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', width: 300, height: 40, marginTop: 40}}
          onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}}
        >
          <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
     </View>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: I thought that this type of menu is a native component in iOS, because I see it in many apps. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For iOS in specific there's a component called [ActionSheetIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html) and you can call it like this:

```
ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
  {
    options: ["Cancel", ...options],
    title: "Select something",
    message: "Some description",
    cancelButtonIndex: 0 
  },
  index => {
    // do something with the selected index
    const listIndex = index - 1;
    if (index > 0) {
      this.setState({ selectedIndex: listIndex });
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only in iOS

```
  import { StyleSheet, Text, ActionSheetIOS } from "react-native"; 

  ...
  OptionButton() {
    let BUTTONS = ["Compartir", "Reportar", "Cancel"];
    ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
      {
        title: "Opciones",
        tintColor: "#242424",
        options: BUTTONS,
        cancelButtonIndex: 2,
        destructiveButtonIndex: 1
      },
      buttonIndex => {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
          case 0:
            this.shareImage();
            break;
          case 1:
            this.reportImage();
            break;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```